# How to implement progress bar in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello i have a requirement of using progress bar in wpf in which i should associate the progress bar with my code , i.e., when i click an import button i have some if conditions and classes to be executed for that it is taking some time so i want a progress bar that shows my user how much percent have been completed please help my query looking for genuine help.

```
{
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog selectExcel = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            selectExcel.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsm";
            MSAccessOperations accessOperations = new MSAccessOperations();

            Nullable<bool> result = selectExcel.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {

                string excelFilename = selectExcel.FileName;
             // Here i want to start my progress bar

                if (excelFilename.Contains("NHE PLUS File"))
                    accessOperations.ReadNHEXlsmFile(excelFilename);
                else if (excelFilename.Contains("Total Build File"))
                    accessOperations.ReadTBXlsmFile(excelFilename);
            // Here i want to complete the progress bar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only showing the code you use to open the file.
What have you tried regarding the progress bar?

To do a progress bar in WPF, add a ProgressBar element in your UI (XAML):

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progress" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
```

Then, update its value in code:

```
progress.Value = 50;
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) and [tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/).

The difficulty here will be getting the progress information from your `Read...File()` methods. You may have to refactor your `MSAccessOperations` class to fire events indicating the progress. But this is unrelated to WPF.

Comment: agree with Xavier, you need to keep updating the progress bar value with reference to your backend code.